# Left join two tables and return first row of matching records in second table

Tags: left-join

I have 2 tables:

Table 1:

```
Order_No | Item_No | Line_No | Amount
---------|---------|---------|-------    
121212   | AAAA    | 1       | 500
151515   | BBBB    | 1       | 400
151515   | CCCC    | 2       | 900
```

Table 2:

```
Order_No | Item_No | Line_No | Invoice_No
---------|---------|---------|-----------
121212   | AAAA    | 1       | 11000012
151515   | BBBB    | 1       | 11002356
151515   | BBBB    | 1       | 11000586
```

I want to join the 2 tables with left join (Table 1 left join Table 2) and return the first match of Table 2 like the following results:

Results:

```
Order_No | Item_No | Line_No | Invoice_No | Amount
---------|---------|---------|----------- |-------
121212   | AAAA    | 1       | 11000012   | 500
151515   | BBBB    | 1       | 11002356   | 400
151515   | CCCC    | 2       |            | 900
```

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's actually not "left outer join":

```
SELECT
  t1.Order_No, t1.Item_No, t1.Line_No,
  (SELECT Invoice_No FROM Table2 AS t2
   WHERE t1.Order_No=t2.Order_No AND t1.Item_No=t2.Item_No
   AND t1.Line_No=t2.LineNo LIMIT 1),
  Amount
FROM Table1 AS t1
```

Comment: Hi Philip,I only want to return the 1st match of the 2nd table. Your suggestion will return all matches of 2nd table.

Comment: Hi sorry I didn't notice that. Modified.

Comment: Hi Philip, if record is not found in 2nd table, will it still return results from 1st table?

Comment: @JingJing It will return null value for field `Invoice_No`, and other 1st table values.

Comment: Hi Philip, not sure why but i just couldn't get your solution to work. Error message kept saying "missing right parenthesis" even though I didn't miss out anything. Is there any other alternative ways?

Comment: What database you used?